# How to use the get() functin provided by the http package?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

I'm trying to get data from a website that hosts Weather APIs (OpenWeatherMap), but as soon as I use the `get()` method, I get an error that says :

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Failed host lookup: 'api.openweathermap.org'

Even tho the URL that I provided is working (I tested it, the API key is working), here is the code :

```dart
String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$latitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$apiKey";
// The latitude, longitude and apiKey aren't not null.
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
http.Response response;

try {
  response = await http.get(uri);
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print("Error when getting data from the url = $url"); // Im getting this line on the console, 
                                                        // so the error is indeed the line above.
}
```

Comment: The error message you are seeing suggests that there might be an issue with DNS resolution for the hostname api.openweathermap.org. This could be caused by a number of factors such as network connectivity issues, misconfigured DNS settings, or even temporary outages on the OpenWeatherMap API server.

Comment: Make sure to replace API_KEY with your own API key

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. My phone had issues reaching Internet, so the code couldn't reach the URL provided.